# PayPal gives an error unless I use its currency conversion

Tags: paypal

PayPal doesn't allow me to pay unless I use its currency conversion. If I select *"Bill me in the currency listed on the seller's invoice"*, it gives me an error - *"You cannot use this credit card for this transaction. Please use another funding source."*

But if I select *"Use PayPal's conversion process to complete my transaction using my card's currency"*, then it shows me no errors and I can proceed to pay.

The problem is that the seller's currency is already the same as my credit card's, so if I allow PayPal to use its currency conversion, I'll be hit with a double currency conversion. But if I don't allow it, PayPal won't let me finish the transaction!

How do I persuade PayPal to let me NOT use its currency conversion?

Comment: Is the credit card is in a different country than your Paypal account, or where you are physically? My guess is that location is more important than the currency being used, due to banking regulations that differ country to country. I would contact Paypal and ask them why.

Comment: @user3169 Calling over the phone is not an option for me, because I can't be sure how much the call will be billed. Paypal doesn't offer other kinds of support it seems. The rest is just searching their forums and Google which I already tried.

Comment: @user3169 I gave up and used their currency conversion. It worked that way, there were no errors. It wasn't as bad as I had been afraid - $14 became $14.15.

Comment: Same issue here, expect until today it worked for me. A bug in PayPal perhaps?

Comment: Working again, seems like this was fixed.